# Item price not being added to basket, along with incorrect quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm seeing an issue with my jQuery code where the:

- Correct item quantity is not being added to the basket
- The price is not being recognised

I think both of the issues might be down to the fact that the information is not being selected from the div currently visible. But I'm not sure. Would anyone be able to help?

jQuery

```
$("#item1").hide(); 
var itemCount = 0;
    var itemPrice = 0;
    $(".basket").html("Basket: " + itemCount + " items (£" + itemPrice + ")");
    $(".atcb").click(function(){    
        var price = $(".sht").text(); 
        itemPrice = price.replace("£", "");
        itemCount += parseInt($(".qty").attr('value'));
        itemPrice += itemPrice * itemCount;
        $(".basket").html("Basket: " + itemCount + " items (£" + itemPrice + ")");
    });
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y6jrmors/5/

Comment: `itemCount += parseInt($(".qty").attr('value'));`  <--- jQuery has a value method. `$(".qty").val()`. But what happens when there are multiple `qty` elements?

Comment: @SterlingArcher - there will be multiple qty elements but I want it to reference the qty element within the visible section **st**.

Comment: Try running `.val` on a jQuery object that has multiple DOM references

Comment: @SterlingArcher - not working http://jsfiddle.net/y6jrmors/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of minor issues. Example, conflicting class names, also, not finding within the `section`, etc.

Here is the code that fixes the issues.

```
$(document).on('click', '.atcb', function () {
    var itemCount = 0;
    var total_price = 0;
    var itemPrice = 0;

    $parent = $(this).parents('.st');
    $parent.find(".basket").html("Basket: " + itemCount + " items (£" + itemPrice + ")");
    var price = $parent.find('h3.sht').text();

    itemPrice = parseInt(price.replace("£", ""));
    itemCount = parseInt($parent.find(".qty").val());
    console.log(itemPrice, itemCount)
    total_price = itemPrice * itemCount;
    $parent.find(".basket").html("Basket: " + itemCount + " items (£" + total_price + ")");

});
```

Please note the minor fixes in the html code too.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6jrmors/10/)